# Configuring plone.recipe.varnish in Plone 4

Tags: plone, zope

I am using `plone.recipe.varnish` 1.2.2 in my Plone application.

Below is a section of my buildout:

```
parts =
    ...
    instance
    paster
    varnish-build
    varnish
    plonesite  

...
[varnish-build]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
url = http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/varnish/varnish/2.1.3/varnish-2.1.3.tar.gz


[varnish]
recipe = plone.recipe.varnish
daemon = ${buildout:parts-directory}/varnish-build/sbin/varnishd
bind = 127.0.0.1:8000
backends = 127.0.0.1:9000
cache-size = 1G
```

I cannot conclusively determine if it works. My Plone application serves on port `9000`. So I want to test if varnish really works by going to `http://localhost:8000` but I get nothing. The browser says `"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000."`

Am I doing this wrong? I have followed the instructions provided [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.varnish) but no headway.

How does one really configure `plone.recipe.varnish` in Plone, and how do you actually test that it works in local development machine?

Comment: "It is not working" is a very vague statement indeed. Do you get an error message from Varnish? Does `http://localhost:8000/Plone` get you anything?

Comment: I do not get anything from the browser. `http://localhost:8000/Plone` gives the following: `"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000."` Is there some setting that I also need to tweak on the plone site-setup as well?

Comment: Then varnish isn't running at all or bound to a different port or interface. Nothing is listening on port 8000 on the localhost interface. How do you start varnish? What log files are produced?

Comment: I've just confirmed it and it is true that varnish was not running. I have started it manually from plone/bin/varnish and now I can access content from port 8000. I am not sure how to start it. I thought that by merely adding it to the buildout as specified [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.varnish) it will be started automatically. Seems like this is not the case for me.

Comment: No, the recipe builds and configures varnish, it doesn't start it. The Plone instance recipe doesn't start the plone server for you either, does it? :-) Use `supervisord` or something else to start and stop your daemons.

Comment: Thanks again. Atleast I know where to look at now. If you don't mind, you may provide an answer to my question so that I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipe does not *start* your varnish server. It only configures it for you.

Use something like [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) to manage the process, or start it by hand with `bin/varnish`.